# cannot ssh into instance created from sourceImage "google_compute_instance_from_machine_image"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating an instance from a sourceImage, using this terraform template:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "sandbox_ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits = 4096
}

output "tls_private_key_sandbox" { value = "${tls_private_key.sandbox_ssh.private_key_pem}" }

locals {
  custom_data1 = <<CUSTOM_DATA
#!/bin/bash
CUSTOM_DATA
}

resource "google_compute_instance_from_machine_image" "sandboxvm_test_fromimg" {
  project = "<proj>"
  provider = google-beta
  name = "sandboxvm-test-fromimg"
  zone = "us-central1-a"
  tags         = ["test"]

  source_machine_image = "projects/<proj>/global/machineImages/sandboxvm-test-img-1"

  can_ip_forward = false

  labels = {
    owner = "test"
    purpose = "test"
    ami = "sandboxvm-test-img-1"
  }

  metadata = {
   ssh-keys = "${var.sshuser}:${tls_private_key.sandbox_ssh.public_key_openssh}"
 }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
      // Include this section to give the VM an external ip address
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = local.custom_data1
}

output "instance_ip_sandbox" {
  value = google_compute_instance_from_machine_image.sandboxvm_test_fromimg.network_interface.0.access_config.0.nat_ip
}

output "user_name" {
    value       = var.sshuser
}
```

I can't even ping / netcat, neither the private or public IP of the VM created. Even the "serial port" ssh, passed inside custom script helps.

I'm suspecting, that since it is a "google beta" capability, is it even working / reliable?
Maybe we just can't yet, create VMs i.e GCEs from "SourceImages" in GCP, Unless proven otherwise, with a simple goof-up not very evident in my TF.

Comment: Is the VM created actually running ? Please check [serial console output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output) and paste the output here. What's the message when you try to connect from the console using SSH button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it actually, and all this somewhere sounds very sick of GCE.
Problem was while creating the base image, the instance I had chosen has had the following :

```
#sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
#sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
```

Maybe I should try with "python3" instead of "python",
but when instantiating GCEs basis this MachineImage, it looks for a rather deprecated "python2.7" and not "python3" and complained of missing / unreadable packages like netiplan etc.

**Commenting the "update-alternatives" and installing python3.6 and python3.7 explicitly did the trick!**

Comment: 1) Why would you install Python 3.6 and Python 3.7? 2) Your question and answer do not state what OS you started with. Therefore, how do we use your answer with insufficient details? 3) Do you understand the difference between the OS's use of Python versus Google Cloud tools and utilities use of Python? 4) I am not sure what you mean by the words "sounds very sick of GCE". Do not rant, stick to the facts and technical details.

Comment: I used ubuntu "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1804-lts". It comes with python3.6 but Needed python3.7 for "pyce".
I didnt think it as OS problem thence did provide that in details. 
3) I dont understand, I never happened to realise that until I could solve it. 
4) you must brush up your tech knowhows too, why is GCE trying to seek "netiplan" package in python2.7, and not python3 (both 3.6 and 3.7 have it installed),